# Private testing chrome extension 'download interupted'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am trying to test out a chrome extension and keep getting a server problem error when I try to download the extension through the web store.  I have added myself as a user to the testing list of users and I have also tried adding a group and using the group in the visibility options.  This extension works as expected when loaded both packed and unpacked through chrome://extensions.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot this error or help me get set up testing the app through the chrome store since 'server problem' is not a particularly helpful error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who met the issue, generally speaking, adding your account or the group under "**also include**" section in the developer dashboard. Then try to republish the extension while choosing a Google Group under **Visibility options -> Private -> You can also include members of a Google Group that you own or manage**. Then the error will go away.

Also keep in mind that you should have waited a little bit after publishing (i.e if you tried immediately after publishing, the old visibility options could have been active).

For this issue particular, you should try the scenario with a single login. From the screenshots, you are trying the download with "**authuser=1**".

Comment: The issue seemed to be having multiple logins.  The only way I got it to work was sign into the webstore with an incognito window to ensure that I only had a single login.